# Generating random numbers in MATLAB

Tags: probability, matlab, random

Edit: The code is edited and new result is pasted.

I am trying to generate random numbers using **randi** command in MATLAB. I am generating 100, 1000 and 100,000 random numbers, respectively, between 50 and 100. Following is my code:

```
clc
clear all
close all  

x = randi([50 100],1,100) % random numbers generated 
subplot(221)
hist(x)                   % ploting these numbers on a histogram
title ('Histogram for 100')


y = randi([50 100],1,1000) % random numbers generated
subplot(222)
hist(y)
title ('Histogram for 1000')


z = randi([50 100],1,100000) % random numbers generated
subplot(223)
hist(z)                   % ploting these numbers on a histogram
title ('Histogram for 100,000')
```

But I am getting following result:

[image]

Is my code right?

Comment: The initial blip in your chart for the $100,000$ example is because you are choosing integers from $50,51,52,\ldots,100$ and your first bar covers eleven integers while the others cover ten despite being the same width (so it is in effect more of a bar chart rather than a histogram).  It also has a relatively small amount of random fluctuation, which is relatively bigger in the other two charts thanks to the smaller sample sizes

Comment: so is my code right?

Answer (score 3):

write subplot command before hist

Like so

```
> clc
clear all
close all  

x = randi([50 100],1,100) % random numbers generated 
y = randi([50 100],1,1000) % random numbers generated 
z = randi([50 100],1,100000) % random numbers generated 

subplot(221)

hist(x)                   % ploting these numbers on a histogram
title ('Histogram for 100')
subplot(222)

hist(y)
title ('Histogram for 1000')
subplot(223)

hist(z)                   % ploting these numbers on a histogram
title ('Histogram for 100,000')
```

Comment: yes that's what i did in my new code

Comment: that's great

good luck